# Move an svg icon along scroll on a specified path

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a project which have a requirement of moving a bee svg icon along scroll, as the user move through the website. Here is the ss i am attaching for refrence.
As the user scroll the bee starts from top and fills in the grey color line with the pink color, and as user scroll backward the bee svg icon moves back.[image: Screen Shot for Refrence]

What i have done so far is the code below.
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div
        style="height: 100vh; background-color: blue; padding: 0; margin: 0; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; color: yellow; font-size: x-large;">
        Main View
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:100%; height:auto; background:url('background-map.jpg') no-repeat;"
            id="route">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 2000" id="svgRoute">
                <path id="path" data-name="Path 71803"
                    d="M50.786,1439.052C-3.729,1320.367,79.128,1289.559,346.6,1288.436c145.008-.609,229.222-45.98,230.488-110.767L561.214,820.374C615.729,701.689,532.872,670.881,265.4,669.758c-145.008-.609-229.222-45.98-230.488-110.767L50.786,219.374C-3.729,100.689,79.128,69.881,346.6,68.758c145.008-.609,229.222-45.98,230.488-110.767L558.918-430.4c-10.105-20.388-36.6-42.469-104.6-42.969C328.9-474.294,285-547.92,310.561-646.052"
                    fill="none" stroke="#eee" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" />

                <circle r="2" cy="18.591" cx="169.887" fill="#CE0F69" fill-opacity=".96" fill-rule="evenodd"
                    stroke="#CE0F69" stroke-width=".55" />

                <!-- car svg  -->
                <path id="c"
                    d="M 3.02008,-2.00446 A 0.384,0.384 0 0 0 2.99106,-1.85469 L 2.99789,-0.835296 2.98889,-0.837286 A 0.113,0.113 0 0 0 2.87613,-0.723255 L 2.88243,0.358786 A 0.113,0.113 0 0 0 2.99646,0.471542 L 3.00492,0.469969 3.01203,1.63073 A 0.384,0.384 0 0 0 3.39872,2.01296 L 8.65185,1.97994 C 8.80663,1.97929 8.93788,1.88712 8.99825,1.75528 9.02715,1.83055 9.09151,1.91021 9.23511,1.90987 L 12.491,1.88891 12.2534,2.32758 A 0.134,0.134 0 0 0 12.4886,2.45492 L 12.797,1.88816 14.2024,1.87929 C 14.7857,1.87543 15.2515,1.40414 15.2473,0.821764 L 15.2448,0.438872 A 0.113,0.113 0 0 0 15.4372,0.357561 L 15.4309,-0.72448 A 0.113,0.113 0 0 0 15.2373,-0.803744 L 15.2349,-1.18664 C 15.2319,-1.76949 14.7597,-2.23574 14.1774,-2.23146 L 12.5876,-2.22247 12.3653,-2.81052 A 0.133,0.133 0 0 0 12.1927,-2.88767 0.133,0.133 0 0 0 12.1143,-2.71463 L 12.3018,-2.22003 9.25118,-2.20155 C 9.08154,-2.20452 9.00514,-2.13533 8.9706,-2.05654 A 0.382,0.382 45 0 0 8.62474,-2.27078 L 3.37245,-2.23957 A 0.384,0.384 0 0 0 3.01965,-2.00355 Z"
                    fill="black" fill-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
        </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Include jQuery from CDN -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Your custom JavaScript file -->
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.css

```
#route {
    /* margin-top: 200px; */
}

.code {
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 40%;
    clear: both;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 100vh 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    height: 300vh;
}
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        drawLine($('#bx_a'), document.getElementById('path'));
        positionTheDot();
        positionCar();
    });

    // init the line length
    drawLine($('#bx_a'), document.getElementById('path'));
    positionTheDot();
    positionCar();

    function positionTheDot() {
        // What percentage down the page are we? 
        var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
        // Get path length
        var path = document.getElementById("path");
        var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
        // Get the position of a point at <scrollPercentage> along the path.
        var pt = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * pathLen);

        var scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
        var maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
        var path = document.getElementById("path");
        // Calculate distance along the path the car should be for the current scroll amount
        var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
        var dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
        var pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
        // Calculate position a little ahead of the car (or behind if we are at the end), so we can calculate car angle
        if (dist + 1 <= pathLen) {
            var posAhead = path.getPointAtLength(dist + 1);
            var angle = Math.atan2(posAhead.y - pos.y, posAhead.x - pos.x);
        } else {
            var posBehind = path.getPointAtLength(dist - 1);
            var angle = Math.atan2(pos.y - posBehind.y, pos.x - posBehind.x);
        }

        // Position the red dot at this point
        // var dot = document.getElementById("dot");
        // dot.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + pt.x + "," + (pt.y + 5) + ")");
    };

    //draw the line
    function drawLine(container, line) {
        var pathLength = line.getTotalLength(),
            maxScrollTop = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
            percentDone = $(window).scrollTop() / maxScrollTop,
            length = percentDone * pathLength;
        line.style.strokeDasharray = [length, pathLength].join(' ');
    }

    function positionCar() {
        var scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
        var maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
        var path = document.getElementById("path");
        // Calculate distance along the path the car should be for the current scroll amount
        var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
        var dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
        var pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
        // Calculate position a little ahead of the car (or behind if we are at the end), so we can calculate car angle
        if (dist + 1 <= pathLen) {
            var posAhead = path.getPointAtLength(dist + 1);
            var angle = Math.atan2(posAhead.y - pos.y, posAhead.x - pos.x);
        } else {
            var posBehind = path.getPointAtLength(dist - 1);
            var angle = Math.atan2(pos.y - posBehind.y, pos.x - posBehind.x);
        }
        // Position the car at "pos" totated by "angle"
        var car = document.getElementById("c");
        car.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + (pos.x) + "," + (pos.y) + ") rotate(" + (rad2deg(angle)) + ")");
    }

    function rad2deg(rad) {
        return 180 * rad / Math.PI;
    }

});
```

Problems i am facing

1- I want to scroll the bee as soon as the div containing the bee scrolls in view, not before that.
2- Instead of moving forward the icon move backward, idk it might be because of some css property of transform is applied on the svg of path.
3- I have the bee icon of my own which i want to use instead of the car icon, the code for the bee icon is

bee.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="46.302" height="47.062" viewBox="0 0 46.302 47.062">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <rect id="Rectangle_37645" data-name="Rectangle 37645" width="34.608" height="36.107" fill="#ce0f69"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  // code for the svg
</svg>
```

4- I want to center align the bee path and want it to be responsive.
5- As long as i am using the car svg the andle for car remains perfect, but when i use my own svg, the angle for bee along the whole journey disturbs and becomes irregular.

Here is the link to the site to whom's code i am trying to mimic

https://codepen.io/yesvin/pen/XymwvX

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with SVG manipulation is always a complex task. A possible approach you can try is embedding your desired svg as **image** inside the SVG itself.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 334 1426" id="svgRoute">
        // This is the path that is being drawn
        <path id="path" d="M170 19s18 32 18 57c0 48-40 51-40 72 0 22 43 31 43 44 0 10-9.4 10-10 23-.7 14 2.3 16 2.2 28-.17 12-14 24-21 32-6.5 7.2-17 15-20 23-2.4 6.8-3.5 23 12 29 16 5.7 32 10 37 24 5.2 13-7.4 26-17 33-9.2 6.6-30 20-26 30 3.5 9.9 27 6.2 27 24 0 18 8.8 13 8.8 24-11 24 16 50 13 71-.46 17-15 23-8.2 42-32 37 1.3 83 26 106 28 20-33 5.7-33 39 2.4 51-28 113-34 139-4.1 18-3.5 41 18 41 8.1-.2 14-6.5 15-14 .37-6.3-6.1-14-16-12-11 1.8-16 11-19 24-1.3 6.6-2.1 17-2.3 28-.43 29 14 36 19 39 2.6 1.8 19 8.8 19 17 10 18-41 7.8-35 28 .61 10 37 22 36 35 8.4 94-128 42-89 130 8.8 36-63 33-60 68-2.1 25 35 32 38 44" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
        //This is the initial dot
        <circle r="2" cy="18.591" cx="169.887" fill="red" fill-opacity=".96" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="red" stroke-width=".55"/>
        //This is the final dot that is at the end of the path
        <circle r="2" id="dot" cy="-5" cx="0"  fill="red" fill-opacity=".96" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="red" stroke-width=".55"/>

       // Here is our magic, an image inside the SVG, put your SVG path in the href
       <image id='c' x="0" y="2" width="8" height="8" href="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/76240/bee.svg" />
    </svg>
```

Not sure if this is the best option but you can give it a try.

**Things to keep in mind while embedding image:**

```
<image id='c' x="offset_x" y="offset_y" width="img_width" height="img_height" href="img_url" />
```

`id`: This is the id that your js is going to apply styles on.

`x/y`: Depending on your image, how much offset you want from the initial position.

`width/height`: How large you want your image to be

**JS:**

One more issue you might face is the rotation that your image is getting. According to the codepen you shared, this piece of code is responsible for updating
the `transformation` property for your element:

```
document.getElementById("c");
    car.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + (pos.x) + "," + (pos.y) + ") rotate(" + (rad2deg(angle )) + ")");
```

Here, you can try playing around with some mathematical functions to make the rotation work for you as expected.

Here is the same code snippet with template literals for better readability ):

```
car.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${pos.x},${pos.y}) rotate(${rad2deg(angle)})`);
```

**Changing Icon position with scroll direction**:

Detecting scroll direction:

```js
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
  //....
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    let alignment = 'down'
        var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop){
       alignment = 'down' 
    } else {
      alignment = 'up'
    }
    lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
    
    drawLine( $('#bx_a'),document.getElementById('path') );
    positionTheDot();
    positionCar(alignment);         
  });
```

Handling logic in the car/bee icon:

```js
  function positionCar(alignment) {
  //...
  car.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${pos.x},${pos.y}) rotate(${rad2deg(angle)}) scale(${alignment === 'up' ? -1 : 1})
   `);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried running my code, actually the problem is that, the bee icon moves along path in upward direction as we scroll down, instead i want the bee icon to move downward. and upward as the user scroll upward
By the way, I was really worried and concerned about how to embed an image in SVG. You made my problem easier by providing a solution. Thanks

Comment: @AliIqbal I have added the scroll handling feature as well. Let me know if this is what you are expecting

Comment: I'm sorry if I couldn't explain my problem statement clearly. My issue is that I have a section containing bee icon, but it stays quite low on the viewport and doesn't fall into view unless we scroll down to it. However, as soon as I start scrolling from the top, the icon starts moving. I want the bee icon movement to start only when the div containing the bee icon is scrolled into view.

Comment: Another issue that I'm facing is that when I start scrolling, the bee should move downward when scrolling downward, and when scrolling upward, it should move upward. but it does the opposite, i think you might assume that i was talking about the position of bee while moving upward or downward.